# Is it posible to publish jars from different directories with the same jar name and control which one is used via configurations?

Tags: ant, ivy

I’m trying to add some ivy dependency management in to the build process of a legacy system, so we can manage the use the artefacts we produce, in the downstream projects and development environment in a nicer way than we currently do. However one of our builds (lets call it module-X)  produces two different versions of a jar file in to two different directories for use in the batch based and browser based application as well as some common artefacts used by both. i.e.:

- bin\batch\DataObjects.jar – which is used by the batch processes
- bin\browser\DataObjects.jar – which is used by the browser based
  applications
- bin\common* - jars used by batch and browser

I’d like to setup the ivy:publish so we are able use the browser\DataObjects.jar when depending on module-X with a browser configuration and the batch\DataObjects.jar  when using  a batch configuration, is this possible using a single module? Or am I best off having multiple ivy.xml module descriptors and publishing/using these as separate modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is best answered by your release management plans. Are the files released together and should have the same revision number? If, on the other hand, each artifact has a life of its own and could be released separately then separate modules are best advised.

To help decide, ask yourself the following question. If a change a source file does this result in the need to recompile both binaries? If yes release them together. If no then might be simpler to release them separately.

And finally, yes, when publishing multiple files as part of the same module it's possible to setup two configurations that enable the separate download of each file in a dependency mapping.

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven">
   <info organisation="org.demo" module="myfiles"/>

   <configurations>
      <conf name="default" extends="master,sources,javadoc"/>
      <conf name="master" description="contains only the artifact published by this module itself, with no transitive dependencies"/>
      <conf name="sources" description="this configuration contains the source artifact of this module, if any."/>
      <conf name="javadoc" description="this configuration contains the javadoc artifact of this module, if any."/>
   </configurations>
   <publications>
      <artifact name="myfile" type="jar" ext="jar" conf="master"/>
      <artifact name="myfile" type="source" ext="jar" conf="sources" m:classifier="sources"/>
      <artifact name="myfile" type="javadoc" ext="jar" conf="javadoc" m:classifier="javadoc"/>
   </publications>
   <dependencies>
   ..
   </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Comment: Ended up separating the modules, tahnks